# rewrite content in excel file column php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I need to read an excel file in my codeigniter project. This is my example file.

[image]

I need to rewrite dynamic content(eg %VAR1 and %VAR2 ) in`msg` field with the content in corresponding column.
ie The msg content in first row will be `Dear (John) this I sa demo message. 8952 test`.
The number of dynamic content may vary from 0 to n.(%VAR1, %VAR2, %VAR3 etc).
Please help me to do this
This is my code:

```
$filename=$_FILES["contactFile"]["tmp_name"];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { 
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";

        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

it displays content in each column. But how do i replace with another column value

Comment: When it comes to PHP and Excel, I often use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). Have you tried it with that?